# NSScrollView starting at middle of the documentView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview

I have the following code:

```
[[ticketsListScrollView documentView] setFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, [ticketsListScrollView frame].size.width, 53 * [tickets count])];
[[ticketsListScrollView documentView] setFlipped:YES];


for(int i = 0; i < [tickets count]; i++) {
    TicketsListViewController *viewController = [[TicketsListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TicketsListViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.dateLabelText = tickets[i][@"date"];
    viewController.timeLabelText = tickets[i][@"time"];
    viewController.subjectLabelText = tickets[i][@"title"];

    NSRect frame = [[viewController view] frame];
    frame.origin.y = frame.size.height * i;
    [viewController view].frame = frame;

    [[ticketsListScrollView documentView] addSubview:[viewController view]];
}
```

if the list is large enough (many views), the `NSScrollView` starts at top-left, which is great. For less views (the views do not take the whole `documentView`, then `NSScrollView` starts at the middle.

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: Please be more careful about formatting (and posting complete) code - it requires others to work harder to help you. I assume you merely forgot to paste in the closing brace for your if conditional and added it, guessing that was the end of your code. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are not flipped by default, which means your document view is being pinned to the lower-left corner (the default, non-flipped view origin) of the scroll view. What you're seeing is a view not tall enough to push the "top" subview to the top of the scroll view. I see you tried flipping this view, so you already know about this, but you're not doing it correctly.

I'm not sure why you're not getting an error or a warning when calling `-setFlipped:` since the `isFlipped` property is read-only. In your document view (the view that's scrolled, and in which you're placing all those subviews), you can override it:

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
```

Of course you'll have to put this in a custom NSView subclass and set that as your scroll view's document view's class in IB if you're not creating it at runtime. You'll also need to adjust the frames you use for layout, since you're currently expressing them in the coordinate system of the scroll view's frame. You should be expressing them in your container/layout view's *bounds* coordinates, which will also be flipped, and so, likely different from your scroll view's coordinates. You'll also need to implement -intrinsicContentSize (and call -invalidateIntrinsicContentSize when adding/removing subviews) so auto-layout can size the container appropriately.

Comment: It sounds complicated, even if all I need is a list of views inside a scroll view (like a one-column table, but without `NSTableView` hassle).

Comment: If all your subviews are the same dimensions, a view-based table view is absolutely easier. If, however, your views have differing heights (especially based on varying width), you'll probably find your current approach easier. Flipped coordinates aren't really that hard, even though it sounds it. Take another look at the Cocoa Drawing Guide's explanation of view coordinate systems and "flippedness" for a refresher. It's just a slight y origin / progression adjustment in your code.